# Problem transforming coordination system of this shape

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal

I would like to convert this shape-file to WGS84 / UTM Zone 33N. But I failed in qgis.
What did I do wrong? Assigning the projection doesn't change it...

https://daswirdmanjawohlnochsagenduerfen.de/extern/airports.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not assign the coordinates but use the original CRS and then transform to your target CRS.

First, you open the original file in QGIS. Then, you right click on the layer then "Set CRS" then "Set Layer CRS...". Here you choose EPSG 4326. It overlays well with OpenStreetMap background (tested to confirm)

Then, you right click again on the layer then "Export", then "Save Features As ...". In the dialog file, you choose CRS by setting it to EPSG 32633 (code for WGS84 / UTM Zone 33N). Now your new created layer is using the CRS you wanted e.g WGS84 / UTM Zone 33N.